# Mapping table is empty

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

Below are two tables that has a many to many relation and and also another table that has a relation with the two first. A mapping table is created by Visual Studio with the name `OrderEmployee`, but when I run the application and enter some information to the `Timeunit` create form, the mapping table `OrderEmployee` is empty!

Should there not be some IDs added to that table since it has a relation with the `Timeunit` table or how is this mapping table thing working, when will there be data added to the mapping table? Or is something wrong with my Entity Classes?

```
    public class Order
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ManufacturerID { get; set; }
    public virtual Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

    public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Timeunit> Timeunits { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Order { get; set; }
}

    public class Timeunit
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Week { get; set; }
    public int HoursPerWeek { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public int? OrderID { get; set; } 
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT:
Create Method for Timeunit:

```
            public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Week,HoursPerWeek,EmployeeID,OrderID")] Timeunit timeunit)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Timeunits.Add(timeunit);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.ProjectID = new SelectList(db.Orders, "ID", "Name", timeunit.OrderID);
        ViewBag.ResourceID = new SelectList(db.Employees, "ID", "Name", timeunit.EmployeeID);
        return View(timeunit);
    }
```

Comment: *What* do you add to `Timeunit`? Show the code that doesn't behave as you expected.

Comment: I add the number of the week, numbers of hours and then I have a dropdown option to select the Order and Employee. The code is autogenerated when I created the controller, so I guess there could not be any error there!?

Comment: Auto-generated code is nothing but a reasonable start. It's highly unlikely that it automatically picks up on setting items in collections.

Comment: OK, I guess the problem could be in some of the Controllers Create Action method, I added the Controller for Timeunit. If nothing wrong here, could it be problems in the Controllers for the Order and Employee? What should I look for?

Comment: @GertArnold Hi, just wonder if you had time to see my edit with some of the code from the controller. I find very little info about how to read and write to mapping tables when I search or perhaps I don't know exactly what I should search for. I need to learn more to be able to take my project further. Any tips?